# CSS background-image does not work

Tags: html, css

It does not work When I followed the answer from similar questions

My css file......

```
.tail{
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background-image:url('C:\Users\joseph\Documents\GitHub\Spring2014\CMP342\MainProject\WebContent\WEB-INF\img\login.png');
}
```

in html

```
<div class="tail">
</div>
```

path for image: checked
linked in html: checked

Comment: It works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PG3bS/). It must be the path then.

Comment: It is working http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/3YcSq/

Comment: This "C:\Users\joseph..." is not a URL. It should be `url(file://C:\Users\joseph...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [file:// URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).

```
.tail{
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background-image:url('file://c:/Users/joseph/Documents/GitHub/Spring2014/CMP342/MainProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/img/login.png');
}
```

If your site is not on your local computer, then you can upload it to a service like [imgur.com](http://imgur.com), and link to the hosted image.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to locate the image path starting fron the path where your have you index file.

Let say your `index.html` is located in `MainProject` then you have to use it like this:

```
.tail{
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background-image:url('WebContent\WEB-INF\img\login.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct path don't use backslash for path in css property. CSS doesn't allow the backslash `(\)`

```
background-image:url('C:\Users\joseph\Documents\GitHub\Spring2014\CMP342\MainProject\WebContent\WEB-INF\img\login.png');
```

Try this

```
background-image:url('../img/login.png');
```

OR

```
background-image:url('C:/Users/joseph/Documents/GitHub/Spring2014/CMP342/MainProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/img/login.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `/` instead of `\`

```
.tail{
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background-image:url('file://C:/Users/joseph/Documents/GitHub/Spring2014/CMP342/MainProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/img/login.png');
}
```

However, I'd suggest you to use relative path instead of absolute path. For example, if your `img` folder is the same directory as your HTML file then you can use:

```
.tail{
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background-image:url('img/login.png');
}
```